# change color of character when mouseover javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to highlight (change background-color) of the character that the mouse is hovering over.

how can i do that with JavaScript?

it should produce code similar to this

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus <span id='highlight'>e</span> Lorem     ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: Pure JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: It's tagged with both, so it would seem that either would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your paragraph into characters. Then map each character to a span containing the character, then append those elements to the emptied paragraph. Give each span a CSS `:hover` block:

**jQuery**

```
$cont = $('p');
parts = $.map($cont.text().split(''), function(v){
    return $('<span />', {text:v});
});
$cont.empty().append(parts);
```

**CSS**

```
p span:hover{background:#F00}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7vtL/1/)

---

If you want to leave out whitespace, use an if statement to test the length of the value after `trim`ing:

```
$cont = $('p');
parts = $.map($('p').text().split(''), function(v){
    return $.trim(v).length ? $('<span />', {text:v}) : ' ';
});
$cont.empty().append(parts);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7vtL/3/)

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: The OP asked for Javascript and didn't mention jQuery explicitly. This is a proof of concept that shows how to obtain this effect and has the main task of explaining the effect. Once understood, it is easy to implement in jQuery with much less code.

---

It's tricky to find the character that has been hovered unless you split the whole string into `<span>`s first, like this.

HTML in page:

```
<p id="source">This is an example text.</p>
```

JS in page:

```
var i, tx, html, node;

node = document.getElementById("source");
tx = node.innerHTML;

html = "";
for (i = 0; i < tx.length; i++)
{
  html += "<span>" + tx.charAt(i) + "</span>";
}

node.innerHTML = html;
```

Next, you define in your CSS:

```
p#source span:hover
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here's the full working example page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p#source span:hover
      {
        background-color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var i, tx, html, node;

        node = document.getElementById("source");
        tx = node.innerHTML;

        html = "";
        for (i = 0; i < tx.length; i++)
        {
          html += "<span>" + tx.charAt(i) + "</span>";
        }

        node.innerHTML = html;
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="source">This is an example text.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can probably skip adding the spans around any whitespace characters.   ;)

Comment: What I cared most about is the explanation on how you can achieve the effect and show code that is easy to read line by line as a proof of concept. Obviously you can now decline this into any framework you want, jQuery is not the only one on the world, you know :)

Answer (score 2):

Gonna throw my solution in the ring as well.   :)   It also involves wrapping `<span>` tags aroungs each character (though, only the non-whitespace ones . . . no point in turning an invisible character into a different color   ;)   ):

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $higlightSection = $("p");

        $higlightSection.html($higlightSection.text().replace(/(\S)/g, "<span>$1</span>"));

        $higlightSection.find("span").on("hover", function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    p {cursor: default;}
    .highlight {color: red;}
</style>
```

**EDIT:** I updated the code in my solution to match the sample HTML that you provided.

Comment: this is my favorite solution +1, the idea of toggling classes is a handy one